# What is the actual work of proximity sensor in Windows phone? Communication between device or it works when human body comes nearby the device?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, proximity

I searched a lot about proximity sensor of Windows phone. Everywhere i found proximity device is used for communication for the device. But as i know, Android phone uses proximity sensor for detecting the human body when comes nearby. is there any api available who can detect when human body comes nearby?

Answer (score 1):

I understand it was not reallly clear.

Proximity API is used to communicate between devices.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.proximity.aspx

Proximity Sensor is available to detect if an object is in front of the screen : 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.sensors.proximitysensor.aspx

(all sensors here :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.sensors.aspx )

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a proper proximity sensor usage in Windows 10.

For Windows Phone 8.1 you might can work with the Light Sensor API to detect if something is close to the Phone:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.sensors.lightsensor.aspx

And here some sample code:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LightSensor-Sample-4477824c

Answer (score 0):

Actually the work of proximity is to detect other devices like windows phone , or windows computer through NFC.It detect those devices which has NFC tags

Here is the link for your reference
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj207060(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Requiredcapabilities

and there is no clear explanation on any of the website about the detection of human body or any object that comes near the phone like when the screen turns off while getting it near to our ears may be we can use light sensors to detect object nearby.

I think that this sensor does not have a API and is provided by default by windows phone API if we use the calling API classes